# Changing branches and delete branch in Git after successful pull request

Tags: git, github

I created a branch `"newbranch"` from the master, and then pushed back to the origin.  I then created a pull request which was accepted and merged into master.

At this point should I delete `"newbranch"` from my local and re pull from master to begin working on something new?

What is the proper flow, after a branch has been accepted to master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it is merged into master, you can safely delete it.

Answer (score 4):

Update April 2013:

See "[Redesigned merge button](https://github.com/blog/1469-redesigned-merge-button)" and "[What do you do with your branch after a pull request on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15970467/6309)":

**The branch is now deleted for you**

[image: new merge button]

---

Original answer (February 2013)

The blog post "[Tidying up after Pull Requests](https://github.com/blog/1335-tidying-up-after-pull-requests)" is even more explicit:

> The only trouble is that we end up with a lot of defunct branches after Pull Requests have been merged or closed.
>   From time to time, one of us would clear out these branches with a script, but we thought it would be better to take care of this step as part of our regular workflow on GitHub.com.
>
> Starting today, after a Pull Request has been merged, you’ll see a button to delete the lingering branch:

[image]

The only case when you wouldn't want to delete that branch is:

- if you intent to expend on your current patch, reusing the same branch
- or you have started a few commit that hasn't been merged/accepted, and that would be lost if you deleted the branch:

> If the Pull Request was closed without being merged, the button will look a little different to warn you about deleting unmerged commits:

[image]

That would avoid any accident, deleting a branch too soon.