# Fixing a remote branch after it has been merged

Tags: git, github, branching-and-merging

After completing a bug fix on a separate local branch, I push my branch to a remote and submitted a Pull Request.

After code review it was merged into our main branch.

Then I found I needed to make additional changes for that branch.

So I made those changes on my local branch and pushed them to the remote.

I can't find them anywhere on Github and when I try to make a new branch and cherry-pick the commit, git tells me the commit is empty.

What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that:

- that branch was [deleted after the accepted pull request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15970467/6309)
- that branch (even pushed again) isn't a good candidate for a new pull request (because your new commits should be done on top of the updated master of upstream)

[image: upstream]

You should:

- [pull from upstream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9257901/6309), making sure your local and remote repo have the lastest master from the original repo
- make a new branch from there, with your new commits,
- make a pull request from that new branch.