# Delete local Git branches after deleting them on the remote repo

Tags: git, github, branch, pull, repository

I want to have my local and remote repositories always in sync in terms of branches.

After a Pull Request review on GitHub, I merge and remove my branch there (remote).
How could I fetch this information in my local repository and get Git to remove my local version of the branch as well?

Comment: Do you want to delete your remote tracking branches, local branches, or both? You can actually write an alias (bash or git) that will take all of the deleted remote branches, and find local copies to delete too, all in one command.

Comment: Maybe try using the following commands to come up with something, [`git ls-remote`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-ls-remote.html) and [`git show-ref`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-show-ref.html).

Comment: Also, you might want to check out [`git symbolic-ref`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-symbolic-ref.html) and [`git update-ref`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-update-ref.html).

Comment: thanks for your help, I ended up finding the answer somewhere else. See my response.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I delete all git branches which have been merged?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127328/how-can-i-delete-all-git-branches-which-have-been-merged)

Comment: Related: [Delete a Git branch both locally and remotely](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2003505/456814).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove branches no longer on remote](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726949/remove-branches-no-longer-on-remote)

Answer (score 195, accepted):

### The quick way

```
git branch --merged | grep -v "\*" | xargs -n 1 git branch -d
```

NB: if you're not on `master`, this has the potential to delete the branch. Keep reading for the "better way".

### Make sure we keep master

You can ensure that `master`, or any other branch for that matter, doesn't get removed by `grep`ing for more. In that case you would go:

```
git branch --merged | grep -v "\*" | grep -v "YOUR_BRANCH_TO_KEEP" | xargs -n 1 git branch -d
```

So if we wanted to keep `master`, `develop` and `staging` for instance, we would go:

```
git branch --merged | grep -v "\*" | grep -Ev "(\*|master|develop|staging)" | xargs -n 1 git branch -d
```

### Make this an alias

Since it's a bit long, you might want to add an alias to your `.zshrc` or `.bashrc`. Mine is called `gbpurge` (for `git branches purge`):

```
alias gbpurge='git branch --merged | grep -Ev "(\*|master|develop|staging)" | xargs -n 1 git branch -d'
```

Then reload your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`:

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

or

```
. ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: You can put the commands in an alias and make it a single command. However, since `branch` is a [porcelain and not a plumbing command](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/), watch out for any UI changes in future versions of Git that may break it.

Comment: Perfect! Note that following the Github Workflow the local branch `master` will be deleted.

Comment: Nope pretty sure it stays there (I'm using it everyday and it doesn't seem to do that).

Comment: I copy-pasted the command into my console and it deleted my local master branch

Comment: Yup if your master is not pushed to your remote then it gets deleted like any other branch. Make sure you read carefully the question before you copy and paste anything: as I said, I needed a way to get rid of deleted branches on the remote (branches that no longer existed). That's why your master got blown up buddy.

Comment: If you want to keep your master you and just add an additional grep of `grep -v "master"` after the first one. You can follow that pattern with any other branch you might want to keep.

Comment: FYI if you want to keep multiple branches you can use a single grep, like so:  `grep -Ev '(\*|master|important-branch)'`

Comment: If you want to put this in your `~/.gitconfig` instead, add the following to the `[alias]` section: `gbpurge = !"git branch --merged | grep -Ev '\\*|master|develop|staging' | xargs -n 1 git branch -d"` (no need to use () in the grep expression).

Comment: it would be nice if you could automatically make it so you'd keep any branches whose remote equivalent haven't been deleted; that way you don't have to keep track of master|develop|staging|etc

Comment: More bad advice on Stack Overflow... You just whacked Master with ***The quick way***. Perhaps you should have stated that the ***The quick way*** deletes master even if its not deleted on remote...

Comment: BE CAREFUL if you're a newbie. Adding a git alias and using it in other repositories requires extra care. Not every git repository would have "master|develop|staging" as main branches. I personally don't recommend this method.

Comment: What if I'm on Windows?

Comment: This finds merged branches, but not branches present locally that have been deleted on the remote.

Answer (score 110):

I use the same flow with GitHub, and didn't find the previous answers satisfying me, as `git branch --merged` lists branches which were merged, but not every of them was removed remotely in my case.
So, this worked for me:

`git fetch --all -p; git branch -vv | grep ": gone]" | awk '{ print $1 }' | xargs -n 1 git branch -d`

where:

- `git fetch --all -p`: update local branches status
- `git branch -vv`: list local branches status
- `grep ": gone]"`: filter deleted ones
- `awk '{ print $1 }'`: extract their names
- `xargs -n 1 git branch -d`: pass the name to the delete command

Note: if you prefer, you could use -D instead of -d, which enforces the delete.

For example:

```
someUsr@someHost:~/repo$ git branch -a
basic-testing
integration-for-tests
* master
origin
playground-for-tests
test-services
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
remotes/origin/basic-testing
remotes/origin/master
remotes/origin/test-services

someUsr@someHost:~/repo$ git fetch --all -p; git branch -vv | grep ": gone]" | awk '{ print $1 }' | xargs -n 1 git branch -d
Fetching origin
Deleted branch integration-for-tests (was fbc609a).
Deleted branch playground-for-tests (was 584b900).

someUsr@someHost:~/repo$ git branch -a
basic-testing
* master
origin
test-services
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
remotes/origin/basic-testing
remotes/origin/master
remotes/origin/test-services
```

Reference:

http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches

Comment: I took the liberty to ensure that I'll always do that against master, therefore: 

`git checkout master; git pull origin master; git fetch --all -p; git branch -vv | grep gone | awk '{ print $1 }' | xargs -n 1 git branch -d`

Great script and explanation, thank you for that :)

Comment: Note that `branch -vv` shows the last commit message from the branch. If you happened to have "gone" in that message the `grep gone` would hit that branch too. So, `grep ": gone]"` is probably a little safer to use.

Comment: This is the actual answer to the question. Thank you.

Comment: I'd add one more thing - make to switch to most relevant branch you have.
Otherwise, you will get notices: 
`error: The branch 'feature/SHOP-498' is not fully merged.
If you are sure you want to delete it, run 'git branch -D feature/SHOP-498'.`

Comment: @profuel I'm not so sure if I get your comment right, whereas you say "most relevant branch".
That type of output is exactly the warning I want to see, as it happens for local branches which I didn't push fully - so for me for example they contain some work in progress which is so experimental that is not even worth to be pushed.
So either you push it, then it will get deleted, or you delete it manually, but the warning is needed as you've some unpushed commits into it.

Comment: How about getting rid of grep completely in favor of `git branch -vv | awk '{ if ($4 == "gone]") print $1 }'` -- one less pipe and it's slightly more exact as it only checks for `gone]` in specific column

Comment: Even better: `awk '$3 $4 ~ /:gone]$/ { print $1 }'`

Comment: Apart from needing `-D` instead of `-d` this is the perfect answer!

Comment: @Cas thanks to point that out! I will add a note about it, but given the --force option of -D, I would let the others to choose what's best for them :)

Comment: thank you, this worked for me where the other commands using `--merged` didn't!

Comment: @A.Wan you're welcome, I still use this very same nowadays :)

Comment: This worked perfectly, except for on a particular shell where my user is not given access to `xargs`. For anyone else in that situation, you can pipe to a while loop instead of `xargs`, like so: `...awk '{ print $1 }' | while read -r line; do git branch -D $line; done`

Answer (score 79):

try:

```
git pull --prune
```

which deletes your local branch, if its corresponding remote branch is deleted.

### Updated:

The statement above is not that correct.

In fact, running `git pull --prune` will **only REMOVE the remote-tracking branches** such like

```
remotes/origin/fff
remotes/origin/dev
remotes/origin/master
```

Then, you can run `git branch -r` to check the remote-tracking branches left on your machine. Suppose the left branches are:

```
origin/dev
origin/master
```

which means the branch `origin/fff` is deleted.

So, after running `git pull --prune`, just run:

`git branch --merged | grep -vFf <(git branch -r | cut -d'/' -f2-)`

you can find out all the local branches which:

1. have no correspoding remote branches any more;
2. can be removed safely.

then, `<the command above> | xargs git branch -d` can delete all of them. So, the final command is:

`git branch --merged | grep -vFf <(git branch -r | cut -d'/' -f2-) | xargs git branch -d`

Comment: This answer is not quite correct. The `--prune` flag will only delete remote-tracking branches, not local branches.

Comment: Agreed with @Cupcake here, this doesn't achieve what I'm looking for here.

Comment: Not going to upvote, but this is what I needed after having deleted local branches and then deleting from GitHub but them still existing as remotes in my git remote -v command.

Comment: is there really a way to delete local branch for which remote tracking branch is deleted ?

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for. The one-liner piped commands that delete branches scare me a bit. This is a nice safe option for routine cleanup.

Comment: You can also do `git fetch --prune`, that's my way of choice

Comment: Yet another Git error from advice found on Stack overflow... ***`git pull --prune`*** resulted in ***"You asked to pull from the remote '--prune', but did not specify a branch. Because this is not the default configured remote for your current branch, you must specify a branch on the command line."***

Comment: `git fetch origin --prune` may help in prev. comments case

Answer (score 24):

This should work to avoid deleting the *master* and *development* branches with the accepted solution:

```
git branch --merged | egrep -v "^\*|master|development" | xargs -n 1 git branch -d
```

Answer (score 19):

For people using powershell, this is the equivalent to the answer [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34969746/1297609):

```
git branch -vv | Select-String -Pattern ': gone]' | ForEach-Object{($_ -split "\s+")[1]} | %{ git branch -D $_ }
```

1. Filter all the branches that are marked as *gone*
2. Call `git branch -D` on each of the found branches (using `-D` to delete a branch irrespective of its merged status).

Answer (score 11):

Very simple solution: remove your local repo and clone the remote one anew. May not seem very elegant, but it is simple and you'll understand exactly what you're doing without reading man pages :-).

Comment: Why so many downvotes? I mean obviously not efficient, especially with larger repos, but it does what OP asked. Is there some other reason not to do this?

Comment: Because you'll lose all your local branches, stashes, unpushed commits... it's like fishing with dynamite.

Comment: The same happens when the laptop you are working on somehow gets corrupted, lost, or stolen, so I tend not to keep nothing crucial locally. It seems better to me to just create a branch and push it, even for small features, and delete it after it is not useful anymore.

Answer (score 7):

None of this was working for me. You can see my other answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34969726/550454

But essentially, I now have this in my `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
  prune-branches = !git remote prune origin && git branch -vv | grep ': gone]' | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -r git branch -d
```

Answer (score 7):

In the event that you've just pushed and merged your branch to master, then do the following in git bash:

```
git branch -d branch_name_to_delete
```

If you're currently in that branch it will push you back to master. At this point do a pull with

```
git pull
```

Comment: This does have the advantage over the other answers here of "actually answering the question as asked - in the singular: "get Git to remove my local version of the branch as well?".

Answer (score 2):

I just do that to remove merged local branches:

```
git branch -d $(git branch --merged)
```

and in case you want to remove inexistent trackings too:

```
git pull --prune
```

Answer (score 1):

I've written this one-liner to list all local branches which do not have corresponding remote branch:

```
diff -u <(git branch|sed 's/..//') <(git branch -r|sed 's/..origin\///')|tail -n +4|sed -n "s/^-//p" -
```

After this done, deleting these local branches is easy with `xargs`:

```
diff -u <(git branch|sed 's/..//') <(git branch -r|sed 's/..origin\///')|tail -n +4|sed -n "s/^-//p" -|xargs -r git branch -d
```

Comment: this is listing me `master` too, it doesn't work as expected; be careful

Answer (score 0):

I wanted a PowerShell implementation like [amaechler's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17983068/delete-local-git-branches-after-deleting-them-on-the-remote-repo/35735148#35735148), but I also wanted the `git remote prune origin` behavior and `git prune-branches` alias from [Karl Wilbur's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17983068/delete-local-git-branches-after-deleting-them-on-the-remote-repo/34969746#34969746).

Adding `remote prune` was straightforward:

```
git remote prune origin; git branch -vv | Select-String -Pattern ': gone]' | %{($_ -split '\s+')[1]} | %{ git branch -d $_ }
```

Adding the `prune-branches` alias was more difficult. Due to the command line chaining by git, cmd, and PowerShell (with different quoting syntaxes), I couldn't get a single-line `config alias` command to work. However, if you execute the following three lines in a PowerShell console, then it will add the `git prune-branches` alias globally:

```
$command = "git remote prune origin; git branch -vv | Select-String -Pattern ': gone]' | %{(`$_ -split '\s+')[1]} | %{ git branch -d `$_ }"
$base64 = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($command))
git config --global alias.prune-branches "!powershell.exe -EncodedCommand $base64"
```

Answer (score -2):

The voted answer does have the potential to delete master. Consdier the below practical example.

I had two feature branches hemen_README and hemen_BASEBOX which were merged into develop, and then develop was merged into master. The feature branches hemen_README and hemen_BASEBOX were deleted remotely but were still showing up locally. Also i am not on master locally, but on develop.

In that case

```
    hemen@hemen-MXC061:~/data/projects/vagrant-webdev$ git branch -v -a
    * develop                      671ad6c Merged in hemen_README (pull request #1)
        hemen_BASEBOX                a535c0f added global exec paths to puppet manifest
        hemen_README                 ba87489 Updated Readme with considerable details
        master                       8980894 [behind 7] Initial Vagrantfile, works for vagrant up. Also initial .gitignore
        remotes/origin/develop       671ad6c Merged in hemen_README (pull request #1)
        remotes/origin/hemen_BASEBOX a535c0f added global exec paths to puppet manifest
        remotes/origin/hemen_README  ba87489 Updated Readme with considerable details
        remotes/origin/master        2f093ce Merged in develop (pull request #3)
```

So if i run the above partial command

```
    hemen@hemen-MXC061:~/data/projects/vagrant-webdev$ git branch --merged | grep -v "\*"
        hemen_BASEBOX
        hemen_README
        master
```

Notice that it shows master too, which will eventually be deleted.

In any case I was able to do it. I am sharing my session log with you on how I achieved that.

```
    hemen@hemen-MXC061:~/data/projects/vagrant-webdev$ git remote prune origin --dry-run
    Pruning origin
    URL: git@bitbucket.org:hemenkapadiapublic/vagrant-webdev.git
     * [would prune] origin/hemen_BASEBOX
     * [would prune] origin/hemen_README
    hemen@hemen-MXC061:~/data/projects/vagrant-webdev$ git remote prune origin 
    Pruning origin
    URL: git@bitbucket.org:hemenkapadiapublic/vagrant-webdev.git
     * [pruned] origin/hemen_BASEBOX
     * [pruned] origin/hemen_README
```

I just checked whay will be pruned and then pruned it. looking at branch command below we have taken care of remotes

```
    hemen@hemen-MXC061:~/data/projects/vagrant-webdev$ git branch -v -a
    * develop                671ad6c Merged in hemen_README (pull request #1)
        hemen_BASEBOX          a535c0f added global exec paths to puppet manifest
        hemen_README           ba87489 Updated Readme with considerable details
        master                 8980894 [behind 7] Initial Vagrantfile, works for vagrant up. Also initial .gitignore
        remotes/origin/develop 671ad6c Merged in hemen_README (pull request #1)
        remotes/origin/master  2f093ce Merged in develop (pull request #3)
```

Now go ahead and delete local branches

```
    hemen@hemen-MXC061:~/data/projects/vagrant-webdev$ git branch -d hemen_BASEBOX 
    Deleted branch hemen_BASEBOX (was a535c0f).
    hemen@hemen-MXC061:~/data/projects/vagrant-webdev$ git branch -d hemen_README
    Deleted branch hemen_README (was ba87489).
```

Good now the branches are as desired.

```
    hemen@hemen-MXC061:~/data/projects/vagrant-webdev$ git branch -v -a
    * develop                671ad6c Merged in hemen_README (pull request #1)
        master                 8980894 [behind 7] Initial Vagrantfile, works for vagrant up. Also initial .gitignore
        remotes/origin/develop 671ad6c Merged in hemen_README (pull request #1)
        remotes/origin/master  2f093ce Merged in develop (pull request #3)
```

Comment: Of course it has the potential of deleting master. Please read the question carefully. As I said there, I needed a way to clean things up on my local. That means deleting all the branches that no longer exist on remote. If master is no longer there, then it will disappear on your local machine as well.