# How can I delete all git branches which have been "Squash and Merge" via GitHub?

Tags: git, github, merge, git-branch, git-squash

Ever since GitHub introduced [Squash and Merge](https://github.com/blog/2141-squash-your-commits), all the cool kids at my workplace are using it when merging pull requests. Is there a way to cleanup "Squash and Merge" branches?

The following command from [How can I delete all git branches which have been merged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127328/how-can-i-delete-all-git-branches-which-have-been-merged) does not work for "Squash and Merge":

```
git branch --merged | egrep -v "(^\*|master|dev)" | xargs git branch -d
```

Answer (score 117):

Here's a script that will delete all local branches that have been squash merged into master:

```
git checkout -q master && git for-each-ref refs/heads/ "--format=%(refname:short)" | while read branch; do mergeBase=$(git merge-base master $branch) && [[ $(git cherry master $(git commit-tree $(git rev-parse "$branch^{tree}") -p $mergeBase -m _)) == "-"* ]] && git branch -D $branch; done
```

If you want to run a dry run, you can instead run this:

```
git checkout -q master && git for-each-ref refs/heads/ "--format=%(refname:short)" | while read branch; do mergeBase=$(git merge-base master $branch) && [[ $(git cherry master $(git commit-tree $(git rev-parse "$branch^{tree}") -p $mergeBase -m _)) == "-"* ]] && echo "$branch is merged into master and can be deleted"; done
```

You can then setup an alias like this:

```
alias gprunesquashmerged='git checkout -q master && git for-each-ref refs/heads/ "--format=%(refname:short)" | while read branch; do mergeBase=$(git merge-base master $branch) && [[ $(git cherry master $(git commit-tree $(git rev-parse "$branch^{tree}") -p $mergeBase -m _)) == "-"* ]] && git branch -D $branch; done'
```

Source:

https://github.com/not-an-aardvark/git-delete-squashed

Comment: This worked incredibly well for me. It removed a couple hundred branches and left the ones that I either never finished or were experimental. Excellent answer.

Comment: Super useful, thanks!

Comment: This is awesome.  Do we need to worry about cleaning up all the commits with the "_" message that this creates?

Comment: Also, has anyone figured out how to make this a git alias instead of a bash alias?  I can't get the quotes right.

Comment: @joshkarges What I ended up doing is making a bash script (.sh) and then calling that from the git alias. See https://github.com/dougthor42/dotfiles/commit/6b65e53822391e150e6163d1648c8947f6f9bd05

Comment: I preferred instead to just install the package from this answer's source, so I have an actual "source" of such a complex script I won't be able to maintain if something else is needed down the road. BTW, this answer looks almost like a copy-paste of the script in the package's readme, but anyway...

Answer (score 9):

**Update (2023-11-30)** `git-town prune-branches` [was sunset as of v10.0.0](https://github.com/git-town/git-town/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#1000-2023-10-27), and the CHANGELOG now suggests running `git-town sync` instead.

**Update** The tool `git-delete-merged-branches` did not work great for me. I recommend `git-town prune-branches` now.

The tool [git-town](https://www.git-town.com/) offers [prune-branches](https://www.git-town.com/commands/prune-branches.html):

```
git-town prune branches
```

It then asks for the main development branch. You need to select your `main` or `master` branch:

```
Git Town needs to be configured

? Please specify the main development branch: main
```

Afterwards, it asks for "perennial" branches, which are branches besides the main branch, should be kept. Examples are branches for next versions etc.

```
? Please specify perennial branches:
```

Then, it goes forward with deletion:

```
[main] git fetch --prune --tags
From github.com:JabRef/jabref

[main] git branch -d remove-sav-file
Deleted branch remove-sav-file (was 33c1a869e1).

[main] git branch -d remove-bibtexml
Deleted branch remove-bibtexml (was d21c11337a).
```

### Alternatives

#### git-delete-merged-branches

The tool [git-delete-merged-branches](https://pypi.org/project/git-delete-merged-branches/) allows for a convenient deletion of branches. I especially like the interactive mode.

Installation (requires `python3`):

```
pip install git-delete-merged-branches
```

Then execute

```
git-delete-merged-branches --effort=3 --branch main
```

- `--effort=3` is important to enable deletion of squashed branches.
- `--branch main` is required (as otherwise `master` is used)

#### Other alternatives

- [@teppeis/git-delete-squashed](https://github.com/teppeis/git-delete-squashed#teppeisgit-delete-squashed-forked): With node.js installed execute `npx @teppeis/git-delete-squashed`. Supports `main` branch.
- [git-delete-squashed](https://github.com/not-an-aardvark/git-delete-squashed): Not maintained: Misses functionality for `main` branch.. @teppeis/git-delete-squashed is based on this.

Comment: https://github.com/lzap/git-xcleaner is shell-only interactive one

Comment: FYI: `git-town prune-branches` was sunset as of v10.0.0, and the CHANGELOG now suggests running git-town sync instead: https://github.com/git-town/git-town/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#1000-2023-10-27

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy way to automate this, at least not completely.  (Some special cases could be handled.)  Instead, the best thing to do is to delegate this branch-deleting to the person whose pull request has been squash-merged.  There are several good reasons for that:

1. They are the only ones who can be sure the merge was done correctly.

   Suppose, for instance, that in order to squash-merge a series of six commits, the person who *did* the squash-merge had to, or chose to, change a few characters somewhere in a line or two, for some reason good or bad.  That line or two means that the overall change in the final commit is *different* from the sum of the six changes in the six commits.

   But is the overall result *correct?*  If you did not do any of the changes yourself, how will you know?
2. They are the only ones who know if they intend to *keep developing* on that branch.

   Just because the six commits on `feature/tall` were squashed into one commit added to `devel` does not mean that `feature/tall` is *all done*.  They may have several more commits to add; they may want to rebase `feature/tall` onto `devel` again, dropping the six squashed commits in favor of the one six-commit-squash, but keeping another three commits they are about to add.

There are probably some more cases.  These may all be rare; they may never occur in your project; but the point here is that branch `feature/tall` is *their* branch, not *your* branch, so they—whoever they are—should be the ones deleting it when it's done.

Note that when you pick up `feature/tall` you have your own Git rename it to `origin/feature/tall` (assuming your remote is named `origin`).  If you are experimenting with it, and `git checkout feature/tall`, your Git makes a copy for you.  Once they delete `feature/tall` and you run `git fetch origin --prune`, your Git deletes your `origin/feature/tall`.  So now the problem is simpler and *can* be automated: [find branches whose "upstream" is gone, and delete those](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28020809/1256452).  (The one line script in this answer has some minor flaws; see the comments; a fancier one would use `git for-each-ref` and look up each branch's upstream setting with `git rev-parse`, but that's probably overkill.)

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer an interactive tool with TUI (text-based user interface), I wrote a tool called git xcleaner. It can find merged branches, rebased branches (commits with the same commit message), pruned branches or manually selected branches.

https://github.com/lzap/git-xcleaner

Answer (score 0):

The answer in this post is also useful https://medium.com/opendoor-labs/cleaning-up-branches-with-githubs-squash-merge-43138cc7585e

Adapted slightly to allow any origin name and prevent deletion of popular branches I use this:

```sh
git fetch --all
REMOTE=$(git remote)
comm -12 <(git branch | sed 's/ *//g') \
  <(git remote prune $REMOTE | sed 's/^.*$REMOTE//g') \
  | grep -v -e main -e master -e develop \
  | xargs -L1 -J % git branch -D %
```

Answer (score -4):

```bash
cd ..
rm -rf <dirname>
git clone <insertgitpath>
```